# C++ cin , Segment fault 11

Tags: c++, cin

This gives me seg fault 11 when I input the string.
Why am i getting the seg fault?
It's so simple... where is the seg fault coming from?

```
int main(){
    char * str;
    printf ("please enter string : ");
    cin >> str;
    // reverse_str(str);   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have not allocated any memory to `str`. So you are trying to essentially write to a pointer which cannot hold the string. Essentially this leads to an Undefined Behavior and a seg fault.

The solution is:
You should use **[std::string](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=std::string&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/&ei=Nr26Tt-9AYXMhAeKuf27Bw&usg=AFQjCNHYSO65lBUum_PPFu0nJcwzb0EW9w)** instead of pointer.

```
std::string str;
std::cout<<"please enter string :  ";
std::cin >>str;
```

Also, try not to mix C and C++.
Use `streams` in C++ not `printf`

---

Alternatively, there are 2 other approaches:

**Not so good other Approach 1:**
You can allocate memory to `str` by making it an fixed size array:

```
#define MAX_INPUT 256
char str[MAX_INPUT]={0};
```

**Drawback:**
This would require that you need to know the length of the maximum input that user can enter  at compile time, Since **[Variable Length Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)** are not allowed in C++.

**Not so good other Approach 2:**
You could allocate memory dynamically to `str` using `new []`.`str` will be a pointer in this case.

```
#define MAX_INPUT 256
char *str = new char[MAX_INPUT];
```

**Drawback:**
Again this approach has the drawback of knowing how much memory to allocate at compile time in this case,since user inputs the string. Also, You need to remember to deallocate by calling `delete[]` or you leak memory.
Also, try to avoid using `new` as much as possible in C++.

**Conclusion:**
Best solution here is to use `std::string` because it saves you from all above problems.

Comment: for later on, If i want the string to be in the form  of char * instead of string, what should i do?

Comment: @kiki: You can still extract the `char *` from `std::string` using the function [std::string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).Alternatively,If you want to stick to using `char *` the **Not so good other Approach 2** in the above answer explains that in detail.

Answer (score 3):

`str` doesn't point to anything sensible. You need to have a memory to write to.

```
std::string str;
std::cout << "please enter string: ";
std::cin >> str;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::string` instead.

Your declaration:

```
char * str;
```

declares only a pointer, but does not allocate a memory region for the string to be stored. The solutions could have been

```
char str[256];
```

or

```
char * str = new char[256];
```

However, they are *very* bad style because you would then have to check and control the size of input each time you want to write to it.

C++ provides `std::string` to store strings. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line, `char * str` declares a raw pointer and doesn't initialize it or allocate any memory.  That means it could point anywhere, and most likely not somewhere valid or useful.   You most likely segfault when you try to use it on the 3rd line.  Can you use `std::string` instead?  It'll be much easier and safer than raw C-strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string`.

Or, if you just want to use char * (discouraged):

```
char * str = new char[256];
cin >> str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory first for `str`. You declared only a pointer

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SIZE_OF_BUFFER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults occur when a program accesses memory that doesn't belong to it. The pointer `str` is not initialized. It doesn't point at any memory. The stream-extraction operator `>>` doesn't allocate new memory for the string it reads; it expects the pointer to already point to a buffer that it can fill. It doesn't know that `str` is garbage, though. It assumes it's a valid pointer and attempts to write into that memory. Since the memory at that garbage address doesn't belong to your program, the OS halts it with a segmentation fault.

Read into a `std::string` instead. Better yet, use `std::getline` so the user can enter a string with spaces; the `>>` operator will only read up to the first whitespace character.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(cin, str);
```